# eclipse RCP, how to create submenu without extension point

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm implementing a navigator without using Common Navigator Platform but using pure java code. for know, i want to implement a context menu of this navigator. i want to add a actionset which has subactions, which like "New" action in "Java Package" view. i mean use pure java code. if that's impossiable, please show me the way of extension-point. thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without using an extension point?  I haven't checked, but this might be possible.  However, you'd be using internal APIs, and this is not recommended.

Comment: Hi, because this menu is not based on extension point, only thw view is. so i want to do it programatically. can you please show me how to insert a submenu(just several actions) to an exsiting context menu.